# How do you programmatically set UISearchDisplayBar inside the NavigationBar for UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I currently have a table view controller and have placed a UISearchDisplayController on top or above the my table view controller inside the interface builder. Inside the viewDidLoad of my implementation file I go ahead and assign the searchbar to the navigationItem.titleView. The problem that I now have is that there is a bit more space in the first table view cell because it still thinks that the searchdisplaycontroller is there. You can see it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSKLk.jpg

Here is code:

.h file

```
@interface searchTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    UISearchBar *searchDrugBar;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchDrugBar;
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    searchDrugBar.placeholder = @"Search for info";

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive: YES animated: YES];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the searchBar programatically, I don't see any added value from creating it in the storyboard unless you have your own reason.

First remove it from the storyboard then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchDrugBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchDrugBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,44); // it could be unnecessary
    searchDrugBar.delegate = self;
    searchDrugBar.placeholder = @"Search for info";

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive: YES animated: YES];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: I had attempted this before and the reason that I didn't do this is because the Navigation Bar hides and the search bar hides with it and the screen turns grey with a white box atop. Here is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/Mk1gIPT.png

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBarTop;
```

=> to pur searchbar left/right :-

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
```

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem new];
    ...
}
```

==> Here Given more Reference It might be Useful I hope it work for You..

[How to animate add UISearchBar on top of UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593599/how-to-animate-add-uisearchbar-on-top-of-uinavigationbar)