# Totally hide search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar

I would like to show a search bar when the user clicks on a search button.  I have found that a lot of people use an offset to hide the search bar on launch.  However, is there a way to really hide it, something like a .hidden property?

This is the offset approach but the search bar is still there just offset out of view temporarily.  I would like it to really disappear unless needed.

I guess the other approach is to create a new view controller and launch that when the search button is clicked but that is additional overhead..especially as I have a number of these tableviews.  Thx for any ideas.

```
in ViewDidLoad:
 UISearchBar *searchBar;
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 44)];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;



In viewWillAppear:

[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: UISearchBar is a subclass of UIView so it has also .hidden property

Comment: You can also nullify or remove searchbar from self.tableView.tableHeaderView

Comment: This is one way to do it without leaving empty space. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593599/how-to-animate-add-uisearchbar-on-top-of-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hidden property 
To hide the search bar use

```
searchBar.hidden = true
```

To unhide is just set it to false!
Hope this helps