# How to I conceal the search bar and make it appear when a button is pressed

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar

How to make a `SearchBar` `Controller` hide itself when the view is loaded and then appears when a button is pressed before disappearing again when you scroll upwards. Snapping the search function right up and concealing it until the button is pressed again.

[image: I'm using storyboard to create this, am I doing it correctly?]

Am I doing this right?  I've looked up tutorials and they all point to adding the `Searchbar` to a `TableHeaderView`. I wonder is there a `TableHeaderview` when the `TableView` is set to static.

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a really good guide here to animate a searchbar at the navigation bar when the search button is pressed.

[How to animate add UISearchBar on top of UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593599/how-to-animate-add-uisearchbar-on-top-of-uinavigationbar)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for but  this will work.

In your viewdidload:

YourTextFied.alpha = 0.0

Change YourTextField to the name of your outlet and that will hide the code when the view loads.

When the button is pressed simply run the code:

YourTextField.alpha = 1.0

Answer (score 0):

you can use view.hidden = true before the view get loaded and then view.hidden = false when button get pressed